# R: plot a plane in 3D

Tags: r, plane, plot3d

I am trying to add the z=0 plane to a 3D plot. The code I use is

```
library(plot3D)
zero = matrix(0, 20, 20)
persp3D(x=seq(1,20), y=seq(1,20), z = Delta_B, theta = 20, xlab = "D", ylab = "IR", zlab = "B increment")
persp3D(x=seq(1,20), y=seq(1,20), z = zero, col = "black", add = T)
```

But the z=0 plane does not appear.[image]

If I jitter the plane with

```
zero = jitter(matrix(0, 20, 20))
```

Then I can see it properly.

[image]

In fact trying to plot the plane alone produces and empty graph.

```
persp3D(x=seq(1,20), y=seq(1,20), z = zero, col = "black")
```

[image]

**EDIT**

A partial solution would be to use

```
zero = jitter(matrix(0, 20, 20)) / 10000
```

which results in a plane that is indistinguishable from the intended one.

[image]

Comment: What package does `persp3D` come from? There's `persp3d` in `rgl` but no `persp3D` in that or base R. Also your examples aren't reproducible.

Comment: The package is `plot3D`. The `Delta_B` surface is not reproducible but the second example where I plot the plane alone is. I guess once that is solved adding it to an existing plot should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Something is failing whenever `persp3D` is presented with a constant matrix. Usually this is because the software is trying to compute the scale of the Z range and divides by zero. I'd only expect to see this when plotting a constant plane on its own though, not when adding one.

For example, `base::persp` will error:

```
> persp(zero)
Error in persp.default(zero) : invalid 'z' limits
```

If you want a fully reproducible example, create a `Delta_B` thus:

```
> Delta_B = matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:20,1:20),1,function(r){sum(r)-20}),20,20)
```

Then:

```
> persp3D(x=seq(1,20), y=seq(1,20), z = Delta_B, theta = 20, xlab = "D", ylab = "IR", zlab = "B increment")
> zero = matrix(0, 20, 20)
> persp3D(x=seq(1,20), y=seq(1,20), z = zero, col = "black", add = TRUE)
```

Does not show the `zero` plane. But anything that makes the `zero` matrix non-constant will fix it:

```
> zero[1,1]=0.000001
> persp3D(x=seq(1,20), y=seq(1,20), z = zero, col = "black", add = TRUE)
```

That should be sufficient to submit a bug report to the maintainer. The code for `persp3D` is a lengthy bit of code which I'm not digging into now.